# Open A Particular Website In Chrome Using Shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to open a particular website in Google Chrome using a shortcut.
Example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open [example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693637/how-to-open-a-particular-website-in-chrome-using-shortcut)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1: Create a Desktop Shortcut.

Go to the website, and drag the <kbd>Lock</kbd> icon to your desktop (the icon appears to the left of the URL).

Reference: [patientrewardshub.com][1]

(You can then edit the name of the shortcut by right clicking and selecting "rename").

**Google Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Apple Safari:

[image: Safari]

Internet Explorer:

[image: Internet Explorer]

## Step 2: Assign a Keyboard Shortcut to the Desktop Shortcut

Right click on the Desktop shortcut, click on properties, choose the shortcut.
For reference: <strike>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140443</strike> (no longer available since Windows 10 was stuffed down our throats).